# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'defer_streamfields' when accessing root in Wagtail page

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I just encountered the problem: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'defer_streamfields' when trying to access the Wagtail page in Wagtail admin.

[image for wagtail page failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnvGI.png)

Accessing a single page (eg. page/527) is working fine.

Some people suggested that the problem can be caused by content type mix up in the database, but I haven't done any database dump before. Can someone offer me some advice on this issue? Thanks!

stack trace:

```
File "C:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 311, in render
    if match:
  File "C:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 177, in __len__
    return len(self.object_list)
  File "C:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\query.py", line 528, in __iter__
    pages = pages.defer_streamfields()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'defer_streamfields'
```

I am using Django==3.2, wagtail==4.0.1. The problem occured after upgrading wagtail from 2.6.2 to 4.0.1

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace? Otherwise it is pretty difficult to guess where that is coming. from

Comment: What versions of Django and Wagtail?

Comment: The problem occured after upgrading wagtail from 2.6.2 to 4.0.1, and I am using Django 3.2

Comment: That is very odd. Did you do your upgrade in steps? (You really should) Searching for that method name, I see it was added in Wagtail 2.13 and is still in use in Wagtail 4+

Comment: Some said that it can be caused by content type mix up in the database, do you have any idea on this possiblility? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry but I just don't have enough information about the state of your code and database to have any suggestions. Would you like to provide more details of what steps you took in your upgrade? And is this is your dev database or a copy of prod or ??? Sometimes `manage.py fixtree --full` is helpful but I hesitate to suggest it since I don't really understand the state of your database at the moment.